# How to pass data automatically from .erb page using URL to another php page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a .erb page and when a user is logged in it contains the data like in below code.

```
<% if logged_in? -%>Welcome, <%= current_user.id %><% end -%>
```

So what I need is to pass this data to a PHP page using a URL, and it should be done without user interaction(without links,buttons) because the user is already logged in. I know some code like 
Link to another site this but I don't know how to do this in ruby on rails, also this should be automatically submitted to another php page in a different server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data is it that you want to pass? The fact that a user is logged in? The id of the current_user? Do you want the user to click a link to this PHP page that passes over this data?

Comment: that current_user.id consist the user id of the logged in user, if the user has logged in. I want to pass this data to another php page in another server without a user click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of demonstration, I'll assume you're making a POST request. You can use ruby's built in Net:HTTP and URI libraries in your controller action method to make such a request:

```
if logged_in?
  uri = URI.parse('http://remoteurl.com/script.php')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  params = { 'id' => current_user.id }
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.set_form_data(params)
  http.request(request)
end
```

You can tailor your specific needs by reading up on [Net:HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html). Also, I recommend making this an asynchronous task with something like [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Comment: If this works for you, you should accept it, so that others may benefit as well.